# Right border (pipe) for email menu

Tags: email, html-table, inline

On our email there is a menu and we would like a border (pipe) between each of the items. I have tried putting in `border-right: 1px solid #ffffff` in a couple of different places with no luck. How and or where does the border code go?
this is what the code looks like:

```
 <div block="editable" name="Navigation Link 2" description="Style With - color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:none;" id="navlink2" key="navlink2" display="link">Help</div>
            </td>
             <td align="center" valign="top" style="display: inline-block; padding: 5px 10px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #FFFFFF; border-right:#FFF>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML doesn't seem complete, you are missing an end quote on your style attribute, and you should really be doing style within a CSS file.

Other than that, your HTML is using `border-right:#FFF` - you should be using something like `border-right: solid #FFF;`

Note the style part (`solid`), you can also use `dashed`, `double`, etc... but the default is `none` so you'll have to specify something.

[**Border Style reference**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style)

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7YdAf/)

If you are still having an issue, it's probably something wrong with your dom structure and you should post a more complete picture.

Comment: From what I have read styles need to be inline for email not an attached css file. We are using an email client and I copied what was sent to me. This is all new to me! I tried the suggestions and I can't get it to work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

smerny is right about your code being messy. If you want html to render even remotely right via email you need to make sure that your html is clean. Validators (http://validator.w3.org/) can help with this. There are lots of pit falls to consider when writing html for an email, more than I can get into here, but to address your specific problem one of these methods should work:

Method 1:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-right: solid"> Help </td>
            <td style="border-right: solid"> Lorem </td>
            <td style="border-right: solid"> Ipsum </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Method 2:

```
<style>
    td {
        border-right: solid;
    }
</style> 



<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> Help </td>
            <td> Lorem </td>
            <td> Ipsum </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tAFXx/)

Comment: I didn't write the code. We are using an email client and I just copied what was there. The styling has to be inline. Unfortunately your suggestion didn't work. Thanks!